# Can I transfer a domain out of Route 53 (AWS) where it was purchased?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, amazon-aws, domain-transfer

The keyword here is *completely*. I'd like to move a domain purchased at AWS to Whois.com, partly for convenience and partly to get away from AWS. But I'd think twice about moving it if I have to log into AWS at all in the future.

I recall reading about the complications of moving domains-that you can move a domain, but it always belongs to the original registrar where you bought your domain. So please set me straight on this.

PS: In light of the answers below, I updated my question.

Comment: The term is _transfer_ a domain, and you can do that from any registrar in which you are the registered contact for the domain. For Amazon see [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-from-route-53.html).

Comment: I know `whois` as the directory of domain contact and ownership records. Is there a registrar that is named that?

Comment: "Is there a registrar that is named that? ". There is one accredited as "Whois Corp.": https://www.whois.co.kr through https://www.icann.org/en/accredited-registrars?page=1&sort-param=name&sort-direction=asc

Comment: In light of Patrick's comment, which registrar specifically are you planning to transfer to? The "WHOIS" part of my answer may be wrong if you are trying to transfer your domain to a company that is literally named "WHOIS", after the WHOIS tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**AWS Route 53** is a *domain registrar<sup>[1]</sup>,* a company that is hooked into the greater domain name system and has a license to sell domain names to their customers and hold them in the customer's name.

To move your domain to Whois.com from AWS Route53, you can follow [AWS Route53's outgoing domain transfer instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-from-route-53.html) and [Whois.com's incoming domain transfer instructions](https://manage.whois.com/kb/node/49).

> I recall reading about the complications of moving domains-that you can move a domain, but it always belongs to the original registrar where you bought your domain.

This is not the case as stated. You can pick up your domain and transfer it cleanly to a new registrar. After the domain transfer is finalized, you can forget about your account at your old registrar, it no longer has any claim over or involvement with the domain name.

After you make the transfer, don't forget to update your DNS provider if necessary by changing your domain's `NS` records.

<sup>[1]: See comments</sup>

Comment: "AWS Route 53 is a domain registrar".  No. It is a DNS provider primarily. "Amazon Route 53 is a highly available and scalable cloud Domain Name System (DNS) web service. " at https://aws.amazon.com/route53/ ; Amazon registrar accredited by ICANN is called... "Amazon Registrar, Inc.", IANA id 468

Comment: "WHOIS is not a company" Unfortunately there is a registrar accredited by ICANN under the name "Whois Corp.", see my comment above. Confusing indeed.

Comment: " you can forget about your account at your old registrar, it no longer has any claim over or involvement with the domain name." Except if the old registrar is the DNS provider, which may exactly the confusion between AWS/Route 53/Amazon Registrar.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Companies often have brand names that differ from their registered company names. As far as I know, domains can only be registered with Amazon Registrar, Inc. through the Route 53 interface. So Route 53 is acting as a registrar in brand and in practice, even though the corporate filing is for Amazon Registrar, Inc.

Comment: I do believe it is important to be very specific on who is the DNS provider and who is the registrar, because feelings like "but it always belongs to the original registrar where you bought your domain. " may be directly related to not clearly understanding the difference between the two. Other than that, "AWS" in the question is neither the brand name of a registrar or of a DNS provider, hence for me the need to be crystal clear on terminology. I still prefer to say that Amazon is a registrar and Route 53 is a DNS service, it seems more correct to me than saying that Route 53 is a registrar.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek My apologies for the confusion. So the domain in question was originally purchased from AWS--so that makes AWS (or rather Route 53) the registrar, right? I have also purchased domains from WHOIS and naively thought DNS provider and registrar are one and the same. So perhaps my question ought to be: Is it possible to change domain registrars?

Comment: "So perhaps my question ought to be: Is it possible to change domain registrars? ".  Of course. It is even mandatory in gTLDs by ICANN rules, and also mostly the rules in ccTLDs, but you don't give the name or even the TLD, so hard to say. Using the same company for both domain registration and DNS provider (two completely separate jobs but related of course) has benefits... but also drawbacks, specially when transfering elsewhere (you might want to change DNS service before the transfer otherwise you risk it to be cut off right at transfer).

Comment: @YCode Again, who are you buying domain names from when you say you are buying from "WHOIS"? Are you buying your domains from this Korean company? https://www.whois.co.kr/

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I think I confused whois.com with WHOIS. I searched on whois.com and Wikipedia, but didn't see a clear statement (that I understand) about whois.com (where one can purchase domains) and WHOIS, the query service/protocol provider. If whois.com is the DNS provider, which company is the registrar?

Comment: @YCode It would be 100% faster and simpler if you edit your question to put the name involved. Then everyone can clearly see who is the registrar and who is the DNS provider, and then people can give you adequate advices based on that.

Comment: @YCode Whichever company you purchased your domain at and pay annual renewal fees, that company is your domain's registrar (edit: or reselling on behalf of your domain's registrar). To change the registrar/reseller of your domain (*transfer* the domain to a different registrar/reseller), you can follow the article in my answer about transferring a domain out of AWS/Route53, plus this article on transferring a domain into whois.com: https://manage.whois.com/kb/node/49

Comment: PS: You can register domain names with many companies, not just registrars. Registrars have resellers and even anyone else can have a website to register domains.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister This is where I got my domains: https://shop.whois.com/domain-registration/index.php

Comment: @YCode I've edited my answer to put all the pieces together. Hopefully it's helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can completely divorce yourself from AWS.   I am unclear where you read that a domain name "always belongs to the original registrar where you bought your domain." - This is largely or totally false, and has been for almost as long as I can remember.

Once you have the Auth code (or EPP code/UDAI or equivalent) and the domain has been unlocked at the registrar, you can transfer the domain between registrars - the only catch is for many domains you need to extend the renewal out by a year.  [ This is true for .com, .net and .org ]

ICANN is the authority body governing .com domains and [has this to say](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-holder-faqs-2017-10-10-en) -  **It is your right to transfer your domain name registrations between registrars.**